# What are "definable integer sequences"

Tags: computer-science, computability

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_sequence#Computable_and_definable_sequences),

> An integer sequence is a **definable sequence**, if there exists some
>   statement P(x) which is true for that integer sequence x and false for
>   all other integer sequences.

Surely, for any sequence of integers $x$, the statement 
$$
P_x(y):=y \text{ equals } x
$$
would make $x$ a definable sequence. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Well, a statement has to be finite.  If you replace $x$ by a precise finite description of $x$, then you're right.  But having a precise finite description is just what makes $x$ definable in the first place.

Comment: What is a finite statement?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wikipedia article is speaking *very* loosely there. The author doesn't say what language $P(x)$ is a formula or sentence *of*. If it can be any language, including all possible languages, including natural language, then you're right, everything becomes, trivially, "definable": for any given entity, there's always a predicate that's true of that thing and that thing only.

As used in mathematics, definability is always relative to a logical theory. Some integer sequences are definable in first-order Peano arithmetic; others are definable in second-order but not first-order Peano arithmetic; ZFC defines more still.

Though you don't bring it up, it's clear that the author has to mean *infinite* sequences of integers: every finite sequence of integers is definable in very minimal systems of arithmetic. In fact, for any finite structure you can come up with, there's a corresponding finite formula (in the appropriate language to represent your construction) which uniquely characterizes it. (It's very much like first order logic sentences which, if true in a model, forces the model to have at least 5 elements, or at most 4, or exactly 17; the bigger the numbers and structures, the bigger the formulas.)

Comment: Since the set of integer sequences is defined in the language of ZFC, is ZFC then enough for all integer sequences to be definable?

Comment: @Bananach I think this is indpendent of ZFC. See [here](http://jdh.hamkins.org/pointwisedefinablemodelsofsettheory/). (I didn't check the link closely, but if I remember correctly Hamkins has a result saying there's a ZFC model where every real is definable. I think that link has that result.)

Comment: @Bananach It really depends on what you mean by "definable". In Hamkins' model (link in Quinn's comment), every element *of the model* is definable in the model. An integer sequence is essentially a real. A fine example of an integer sequence that can't be defined in ZFC (unless ZFC is inconsistent ;) is $0^\#$, whose existence follows from (fairly weak) large cardinal assumptions.